# Eloquent one-to-one relationship to same model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have existing data to work with: I got a table that contains all sportevents called `sportevents`.

```
id ....
name ....
....
```

These sportevents have a pivot table that define relations to the "same" sportevent happened in the previous year and the one of next year. Bit confusing design, but here is the table called eventrelations: I try to explain with years 2018 and 2019

```
id ....
event1: sportevent_id of 2019 event
event2: sportevent_id or 2018 event
....
```

My approach would be to create a Model called `Eventrelation` with the following relations:

```
public function previous(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Sportevent','event1','id' );
}

public function next(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Sportevent','event2','id' );
}
```

and in my `Sportevent` Model I would do the following:

```
public function previousEvent(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Eventrelation','event2','id' );
}

public function nextEvent(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Eventrelation','event1','id');
}
```

Although this is gonna work, I don't think this is the proper way to do it. I have setup other relations with a pivot table, but this one seems to be a bit more tricky considering the existing data structure and the relationship to the same Model.
Any advice would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I made it work the way I proposed above, the reason why I would rather have a cleaner version is to reduce the code (that's part of being cleaner :-)). So here is how I call these relations and how I would rather call them:

```
    $previousEvent = $thisEvent->previousEvent ? $thisEvent->previousEvent->previous : null;
    $nextEvent = $thisEvent->nextEvent ? $thisEvent->nextEvent->next : null;

    // Better would be:
    $previousEvent = $thisEvent->previousEvent;
    $nextEvent = $thisEvent->nextEvent;
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why you should not go with the approach you started with?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I updated the question with the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need a pivot model at all. you can make a relationship with a class itself.

in your sportsevent model:

```
public function previousEvent()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(SportsEvent::class, 'pivot_table_name', 'event_1', 'id');
}

public function nextEvent()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(SportsEvent::class, 'pivot_table_name', 'event_2', 'id');
}
```

if there is only one event, you can add a term `->first()` to the end of relationships.

BUT, you can also simply add two columns, 2018_event and 2019_event and add the ids of events there, and then use hasOne relationship. your call

Comment: Good point with the no pivot table needed. I'm adding the columns and migrating the table eventrelations at the very moment... Thanks! I will post the full solution below, but accept your answer as correct!

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the full solution (Not needing the Pivot table at all)**

I added 2 fields to my sportsevents table

```
previous_sportevent_id  int(11) Null    
next_sportevent_id  int(11) Null
```

I then migrated the data of the eventrelations table to the new columns

```
UPDATE `sportevents`
INNER JOIN eventrelations ON eventrelations.event1 = sportevents.id
SET sportevents.previous_sportevent_id = eventrelations.event2

UPDATE `sportevents`
INNER JOIN eventrelations ON eventrelations.event2 = sportevents.id
SET sportevents.next_sportevent_id = eventrelations.event1
```

In the Sportevent model I changed the relations:

```
public function previousEvent(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Sportevent','id','previous_sportevent_id' );
}

public function nextEvent(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Sportevent','id','next_sportevent_id');
}
```

I can now use the new relations properly and clean in my Resource

```
return [
      'id' => $this->id,
      ......
      'nextEvent' => $this->nextEvent,
      'previousEvent' => $this->previousEvent,
    ];
```

The Model Eventrelation and table eventrelations now can be deleted. I hope this will help someone...